# How to temporarily hold state or the correct design pattern with React.useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My goal is to use the `Promise` within the `React.useEffect` callback.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  getEventData() // getEventData will do setData({...data, ...await response.json()})
    .then(getEventBanner_Photo) // getEventBanner_Photo will do setData({...data, event_bannerData: URL.createObjectURL(await response.blob())})
    .then(getAttendees) // getAttendees will do setData({...data, attendees: await response.json()})
    .catch();
}, []);
```

The problem is: after the `getEventData` method returns a `resolve` or `reject`, and then `getEventBanner_Photo` calls the `setData` method with param `{...data}`. The `...data` has not been updated yet.

My current solution is to `resolve` with params, so the next `then()` will get the value, but it makes the function less isolated.

Comment: Sounds like an application for a [setState updater](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), but i am not sure i get the whole picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get past this issue by passing a function to `setData`. That allows you to operate on the actual current value rather than a closure variable:

```
const blob = await response.blob();

setData((data) => ({
    ...data, 
    event_bannerData: URL.createObjectURL(blob),
});
```

Comment: I have not tested this, but does this mean if I call `setData` 2 times, the last `setData` with callback will have the latest data value instead of the current value during the specific render?

Comment: @kidfrom Yes, the value passed into the callback will be the actual, current state value instead of the one captured at the beginning of the render. You can read about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).